# My webpack is not compiling when i am trying to import mongojs?

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, react-fullstack

When i try to import mongojs to connect to my mongodb,the webpack fails to compile and the following error is thrown.

Comment: mongodb will work server side how you are doing at client side?

You can look this repo for connection of mongodb at server side

https://github.com/dhavalrajani92/react-redux-express

Answer (score 0):

Both `mongodb` and `mongojs` (tbh I have no idea why you would use mongojs over the official mongodb library) are Node libraries only and say that in the first sentence of the readmes, not for the web. Think about it - you wouldn't be connecting to your database directly and manipulating data from the client, that would be extremely insecure.